# Apache2 fails to find the requested URL when accessed via a domain name, but functions perfectly via an IP address?

Tags: apache, flask, apache2, virtualhost, wsgi

I've recently been migrating a small website on a VPS from a rudimentary and static one to the Flask framework, via WSGI/Apache2. However, while access to the website is functional when accessing from a browser using the IP address, use of the domain name brings the standard and nonspecific Apache2 message "The requested URL was not found on this server." My VHost is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName slow.estate
    ServerAlias www.slow.estate
    ServerAdmin my.email@gmail.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/se/se.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/se/se/>
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/se/se/static
    <Directory /var/www/se/se/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried this both with the VHost set to port 80 (and, of course, with SSLify disabled) and with SSL and port 443, with no difference. The problem also persists no matter if I use Apache's older `Allow from all` or the newer `Require all granted` in my VHost. In the VHost above, the website will not work at all. If I modify the ServerName to be the IP address, then it works exclusively when that IP address is entered into the browser. Each time I try and fail to use the website in the above manner, a relevant entry is made in `access.log`, and no entry is made in `error.log`.

I've only found one other person out there with a similar problem to me, and that seemed just to be that their nonstandard TLD was being misinterpreted by their browser, which is why I mention that my TLD is `.estate`. I doubt, surely, that this could be the issue, especially when this issue, unlike the other person's, plagues me across browsers?

Comment: Have you enabled the site in Apache with `a2ensite`? After making changes to the `.conf` file, are you restarting Apache? Under `ServerAlias`, it may be worthwhile to add a catch-all to ensure traffic is routed correctly: `ServerAlias slow.estate *.slow.estate`

Comment: @matigo Apologies: I should have mentioned this. The site is enabled in Apache (hence, I presume, it working perfectly when the site is accessed directly via IP), and I'm restarting Apache with every single change, since making changes to the VHost such as tweaking `ServerName` or the port in the header affects the functionality of the website. Sadly, setting the catchall also does not fix the issue, although the headsup is appreciated and I'll keep it as you suggest!